# plotly linear trend line not updating in shiny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to add a linear trend line to a plotly plot in a shiny app. When I change the selection parameters, I see that the coefficients of the linear model change (using `observe(print(summary(l))`. However, the actual line on the plot seems to stay in the same place.

Here is one plot, where the trend line at least seems close to intersecting the two points:
[image]

In another plot, the trend line is nowhere near the first point:
[image]

Here is a minimal working example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df <- as.data.frame(list("UserID"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                          "QuestionID"=c(4,4,5,5,4,4,6,6),
                          "KeystrokeRate"=c(8,4,6,15,8,6,7,8),
                          "cumul.ans.keystroke"=c(1,7,1,5,1,14,1,9),
                "Relative.Time.Progress"=c(0.1,1.0,0.4,1.0,0.8,1.0,0.8,1.0)
                    ))

ui <- (fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("userInput","Select User", sort(unique(df$UserID)),
                  selected = sort(unique(df$UserID))[1]),
      uiOutput("answerOutput")#,
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("mainPlot")#,
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # filter only based on selected user
  filteredForUser <- reactive({
    try(
      df %>%
        filter(
          UserID == input$userInput
        ), silent=T)
  })

  # filter for both user and answer
  filteredFull <- reactive({
    try (
      df %>% 
        filter(
          UserID == input$userInput,
          QuestionID == input$answerInput
        ), silent=T)
  })

  # filter answer choices based on user
  output$answerOutput <- renderUI({
    df.u <- filteredForUser()
    if(!is.null(df)) {
      selectInput("answerInput", "Select A Typing Session",
                  sort(unique(df.u$QuestionID)))
    }
  })

  output$mainPlot <- renderPlotly({

    if (class(filteredForUser()) == "try-error" ||
        class(filteredFull()) == "try-error") {
      return(geom_blank())
    } else {
      # plot scatter points and add trend lines
        p <- plot_ly(filteredFull(), x=Relative.Time.Progress, y=cumul.ans.keystroke,
                       mode='markers', color=KeystrokeRate, size=KeystrokeRate,
                       marker=list(sizeref=100), type='scatter')
        l <- lm(cumul.ans.keystroke ~ Relative.Time.Progress,
                   data=filteredFull())
        observe(print(summary(l)))
          p <- add_trace(p, y= fitted(l))
          p
    }
  })     
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `add_trace` functionality. You need to provide it the x-axis to be able to correctly plot the `lm` result.

```
p <- add_trace(p, y = fitted(l), x = Relative.Time.Progress)
```

To see the problem more clearly, visualize the results with the entire dataset.

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x=Relative.Time.Progress, y=cumul.ans.keystroke,
             mode='markers', color=KeystrokeRate, size=KeystrokeRate,
             marker=list(sizeref=100), type='scatter')
p
```

[image]

```
l <- lm(cumul.ans.keystroke ~ Relative.Time.Progress,
        data=df)
p <- add_trace(p, y = fitted(l))
p
```

[image]

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x=Relative.Time.Progress, y=cumul.ans.keystroke,
             mode='markers', color=KeystrokeRate, size=KeystrokeRate,
             marker=list(sizeref=100), type='scatter')
l <- lm(cumul.ans.keystroke ~ Relative.Time.Progress,
        data=df)
p <- add_trace(p, y = fitted(l), x = Relative.Time.Progress)
p
```

[image]

So as you would see, `add_trace` was plotting the `fitted(y)` correctly but using x-axis to be `c(0:7)`. I am guessing it is a default passed to `add_trace`, but I haven't looked deeply of the 'why' of this. The dataset `df` has eight points. You instead needed to give the actual `Relative.Time.Progress` values on the x-axis to correctly plot the `fitted(y)` w.r.t. actual `x` values. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! So what exactly is it doing by adding the x-axis?

Comment: Edited the answer, took me a while to figure it out as it is my first time working with `plotly()`. I had thought it was a `shiny` issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Makes sense. Plotly really needs better documentation!